# Event recevier will fire twice when i create a list based on another list template

Tags: 2013, development, event-receivers, sharepoint-on-prem, farm-solution

I am facing is strange behavior inside my sharepoint 2013 on-premise farm. here is my problem:-

1. i have created a custom list , and i added many site columns to it . i name the list "Projects".
2. i created a new event receiver based on the custom list templete, and it is scoped at the web level.
3. inside the event recevier i have methods for ItemAdding,ItemAdded,ItemUpdating,ItemUpdated.
4. now i tested the event receiver on the Projects lists and it is working well.
5. now i saved the Projects list as template (without content).
6. then i created a new list based on the list template, i name it ProjectsNew.
7. now i tested the event receiver on the new list and i have noted that the event receiver will be firing twice !! now i tested the original list and the event receiver will fire only one time correctly.

so not sure why the event receiver will be firing twice on the list created using my list template?. while the original list will be working fine in respect to the event receiver. now i knew that the event receiver will be firing twice on the new list since inside my event receiver i have added some logging (where the event receiver will write to a logs list which i have created), and i can see that duplicate logs entries will be added!!
can anyone adivce on this please. at this stage i do not want to share code.. to see if this is a common problem inside sharepoint on-premise farm ??

Comment: @Waqas this is not a duplicate,, actually i read and tried the approaches mentioned in the  link u provided as duplicated to my question but it did not work.. i am talking about specific case..

Comment: you either have it registered twice, or your code is doing it. There's nothing else it could be.

Comment: @Derek but why this problem will only happen when I create a new list based on the list template which I saved?? Now if the problem is with the code then if I create a new custom list from scratch I will also face the problem ,,, but as i mentioned this problem will only occur inside the list which I create based on another list template